# Can we grant access to an app to post something on a page in facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala, fb-graph

The scenario is I want to post some details on a facebook page created by me from my other app. So want to know how can we give access to app through access token means how can we get the access token for this?

Thank You
Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the `access_token` for you page by enabling the `manage_pages` permission, and then calling the API endpoint: `/me/accounts` to get the `access_token` for all the pages you manage.

You can then use this access token to post to your page using the Graph API call: `/{page_id}/feed`

Comment: Add it to the FB.login JavaScript function under `scope`. Read the Facebook Documentation on `Permissions` to see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at the following URL and the *"Page Access Tokens"* section for information on how to do obtain a token.

[API - Obtain Page Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

Note, however, that there is a known issue when trying to use the **links** api point, if you intend to define your own link in the post.

[Bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/230178987060765)

You'll probably want to use the **feed** API point instead. I've not actually managed to get this working yet though, and I'm awaiting feedback from FB themselves. I'll update you if/when I hear something useful back.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment and time.